# No usb, network and recognized vga after 14.04 installation

Tags: wireless, usb, system-installation, vga

First I'd like to point out, I found some similar questions for my issu, but I cannot comment on them due to restrictions, so I had to create a new one.

I've returned to try ubuntu after several years, and I picked 14.04.1 LTS thinking of it as a safer route. But it has been a huge disappointment so far.

First I tried the downloaded ISO in a virtual machine in W8. I liked it and decided to install with dual booting W8, using a usb flash drive.

I booted to usb, and it was ok, I could test and install with nice resolution and my usb keyboard and mouse working fine.

After install and restart, ubuntu greeted me with a very low resolution, no usb functioning, no wireless, etc. I could not try and fix anything without a connection, so I tried reinstalling over it. Again installation looks fine, but first run - same problems.

Well I'm a noob of course, seemed a Xorg thing to me, but I don't know. How can a system recognize everything while in live-usb install mode, and cant recognize them after install?

By the way, my machine is a Sony Vaio F22M1E, with a Nvidia 540m on it. My onboard keyboard has defected keys so it is hard typing there.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Emre.

Comment: Ubuntu community would help in the old days :(